# Exclude if MacOS

Tags: javascript

Is there a simple way to exclude certain code if a certain OS is detected?

I designed a site which works perfectly well (it's a sidescroller) that when a scrollwheel is used (up/down), it scrolls side-to-side. But if you're on a MacOS laptop and you do a two-finger swipe to the side, it starts jittering back and forth. Is there a way to exclude this small snippet of side-scrolling javascript?

Comment: So what about those Mac users that use a regular up/down scrolly mouse? Or Windows users that have side-scroller mice? Shouldn't you be more concerned about making the site compatible using either type of scrolling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the navigator.platform property

```
document.write("Platform: " + navigator.platform);
```

Return types for navigator.platform are: "Win32", "Linux i686", "MacPPC", "MacIntel", "Other"

So you can do something like:

```
if(navigator.platform != "MacPPC" && navigator.platform != "MacIntel")
{
    // put scrolling stuff here
    // you actually don't need the MacPPC check 
    // b/c the laptops with swiping are all Intel based I believe
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to try this out. I think you're right about the powerpc, so I'll probably leave that out so the horizontal scroll will still function properly with the traditional scrollwheel. Thanks.